# CSS: How to prevent contents of scrollable div from appearing behind a fixed div

Tags: css, html

Got a message_container div which has a fixed scrollable message_header div and a scrollable message_body div. Issue I am having is that the contents of message_body div is/was located behind the fixed div. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** I made modifications, I now have an overflowing message_header div and a message_body div. The message_header is great, the message_body looks okay, but I still don't want to have it scrolling up behind the message_header div. How do I correct this? Just to be clear, this code is located in a modal window, I didn't include that cause I didn't feel that it was necessary to solve my problem.

I have the issue duplicated at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcfTc/34/). I made the first content entry longer which appears behind the header div, and is seen when you scroll. I wanted the contents to start beneath the fixed header div, not behind it.

CSS Snippet:

```
.message_container{
    width=600px;
    height=395;
}

.message_header{
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: fixed;
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

.message_body{
    overflow-y:auto;
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="message_container">
    <div class="message_header">
        <p> test </p>
        <p> test </p>
        <p> test </p>
        <p> test </p>
    </div>
    <div class="message_body">
        <p>content is longer</p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
                <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
                <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
                <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
                <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
        <p>content </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** How can people down vote without giving a reliable answer? I think this down voting thing needs to be questioned. I have searched the site. I have played with this issue long enough. I am here asking for assistance. Thank you.

**Edit:** renamed css classes to be less generic.

**Solution:**

As provided by @Pete below. The message_body div and the message_head div lacked definition of their widths and heights even thought the message_container was (later) defined with a weight and height. I updated my example and here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/kcfTc/59/

The CSS snippet is:

```
.message_container{
    width=600px;
    height=395;
    position: relative; //new
}

.message_header{
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: fixed;
    width:600px;  //new
    height:50px;  //new
    background-color: white;  //modified
    overflow-y:auto;
}

.message_body{
    overflow-y:auto;
    top:55px;        //new
    bottom:0;        //new
    left:0; right:0; //new
    width: 100%;     //new
    position: absolute;//new
}
```

Comment: it's because you're scrolling the actual html body rather than the div.body, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/kcfTc/15/

Comment: This stuff is actually all inside a modal window. What you have done is what I want, but it changes the situation. Why is it that when I set a div to overflow-y: auto I am scrolling the html body and not the div body?

Comment: you haven't given the div a set height so it will just continue to grow

Comment: @Pete On the modal window I have does have a well defined height and width. Trtuhfully I had issues with an <hr> object that when a inner div had a width of 100% the <hr> element somehow broken free of the parent div. I got that under control now. I just want the contents of the div on the bottom to scroll to the div above it and nothing more. Without providing a strict set of limits.

Comment: so you have a height style for `.message_body`, then why isn't it in the css shown above?  Overflow-y doesn't work without a height set as how will it know what is overflowing content or not

Comment: Thank you. I just needed to define better limitations on the message_header and message_body div. I also added the message_containers height in the example. Now to go back and try this in my real world scenario.

Comment: @Pete ah now my message_header is much wider than my message_body when I have both set to width 100% and the contents have yet again are behind my header, I see them at the top. Here is the updated version, actually the part behind was also happening again. http://jsfiddle.net/kcfTc/49/ **Modified the example to clearly demo what occurs when the width of the message_header is set to 100%

Comment: Okay so I modified the width of the message_header div to be equal to that of message_container div (200px) and it works. Could you please explain why?

Comment: because your header is position fixed, it means that it is being moved relative to the viewport which usually means it will take the width of the viewport if % is used, your other one is relative to the container so takes the width of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As provided by @Pete below. The message_body div and the message_head div lacked definition of their widths and heights even thought the message_container was (later) defined with a weight and height. I updated my example and here is the link :

http://jsfiddle.net/kcfTc/59/

The CSS snippet is:

```
.message_container{
    width=600px;
    height=395;
    position: relative; //new
}

.message_header{
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: fixed;
    width:600px;  //new
    height:50px;  //new
    background-color: white;  //modified
    overflow-y:auto;
}

.message_body{
    overflow-y:auto;
    top:55px;        //new
    bottom:0;        //new
    left:0; right:0; //new
    width: 100%;     //new
    position: absolute;//new
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/vdecree/kcfTc/10/

I think i'm seeing your problem, however I'd take a look at the structure as it could be better. But you simply need some padding on the top of your body.

Edit*— this is a version just to make things clearer so we can focus on that div you named `.body` which I've changed to `.content` to avoid confusion with the `body` element. I've made the black background just so we focus on what you're trying to achieve with the content div. Is there not what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/vdecree/kcfTc/22/ - I'd love to help you get what you need but there are some details that are unclear.

**css:**

```
.body{
    overflow-y: visible;
    padding-top: 60px; /* push content down below fixed element */
}
```

Comment: faster than i was :( , im not a fan of :auto, since it always does more than i want...  may add that you can achieve the same with :visible

Comment: Read the question again: "I wanted the contents to start beneath the fixed header div, not behind it." My solution makes the content start BENEATH the fixed element as requested.

Comment: ..... :scroll adds a scrollbar, which is definetily unwanted change it to :auto again or to :visible

Comment: @FelixLahmer sorry, my mistake. Changed with your suggestion.

Comment: I have done this, but the header's height is not fixed, so I cannot guess the padding-top. I'm sure I'll have a limit set, but when scrolling the contents of the body is still behind the header. I want the contents to start beneath the header not behind it. So padding-top is like a cheat to the problem.

Comment: `overflow:scroll;` has a lot of issues on most mobile browsers, I always try to avoid it unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: (Or unless you don't care about mobile)

Comment: @user2672744 If you didn't have a set height you could use jQuery to dynamically take the height of the fixed item and set padding to the same amount. Although it'd be easier if you did have a fixed height in mind

Comment: @mastazi - not doing this for mobile. I will now see if I allow for a fixed height and make the contents of the head overflow what will occur.

Comment: @Doidgey - nice, but I didn't want to restrict myself to specific height in case I was browsing across different devices. So the extra effort makes it all the worth while. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just give to `.body` a margin-top equal to the height of the fixed div. This way the content div is stacked below the fixed one.

EDIT: also set `top:0;` for `.header` and the fixed div will remain at the top.

Comment: Margin will not work without pushing the fixed item down as well—with the HTML structure adopted by the op.

Comment: done and tried, that causes the whole div including the header div to lower. I have tried numerous things.

Comment: I'm not talking about `<body>`, I'm talking about the div with class="body", the OP who chose a confusing name for the class.

Comment: Agreed, although the fact still stands adding margin-top to the div with a class of body still wouldn't work. Padding is key here.

Comment: Buecause it is also needed `top:0;` for `.header`. See here http://jsfiddle.net/3MQjA/1/

Comment: Sorry I have edited the url check it now (previous link was wrong)

Comment: @mastazi - okay got me there, body is a bad choice. I renamed them to be less generic.

Comment: @user2672744 I'm wondering if you have seen the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3MQjA/1/ I think `top: 0;` is a reasonable solution since normally, when you you use `position: fixed;`, then you should define that position.

Answer (score 0):

This is going off of your original [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93fqnw3u/) link:

Changes to CSS include giving a top margin rather than just using "top" and putting that at 65px for a little more room, and defining height and width as you mentioned. I did include a border so that if you copy and paste this into jfiddle the area is easily viewed. Obviously just remove that border if it isn't wanted.

**CSS**

```
.message_body{
position: absolute;
margin-top:65px;
height: 100px;
overflow-y:auto;
width: 500px;
border: 2px solid darkgray;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but you can still view the list behind the header. Review the solution that I posted and checked. I gave credit to the person who advised me. :)